# Should i run Carbon-relay or carbon-cashe or both?

Tags: graphite

I want to ask about the Graphite carbon daemons.
https://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/latest/carbon-daemons.html

I would like to ask while running a carbon-rely.py, should i also run carbon-cache.py or the relay is okay?

Regards
Murtaza

Comment: Depends on what you want to achieve, I suppose. A carbon-relay standalone has no use afaik since it needs to relay the data somewhere to a carbon-cache. So you need at least a carbon-cache and then optionally a relay (e.g. in case of performance issues..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Carbon-relay only resends data to one or more destinations, so it needed only if you want fork data into several points. Example schemas can be:

- save locally and resend to another node (cache or temporary-storage and relay)
- resend all data into multiple remote daemons (multiple remote storages)
- save all data in multiple local daemons (parallel storage & redundancy)
- save different data sets in multiple local daemons (performance)
- ... other cases ...

So,
in case you need store data locally - you have to use carbon-cache. 
in case you need fork data flow on the node,- you have to use carbon-relay before or instead carbon-cache

Answer (score 0):

[Carbon relay](http://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/latest/carbon-daemons.html) is used when you set up a cluster of graphite instances. However, a carbon cache does not need a cluster;

Reg [Carbon cache](http://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/latest/carbon-daemons.html): As we all know that write operations are expensive; Graphite enables collected data to be collected in a cache where the [graphite webapp](http://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/latest/config-local-settings.html) can be used irrespective of a cluster to read and display the most recent data recorded into graphite ( irrespective of whether it was written into disk).

Hope this answers your question.